# instantiate an NSArray with integers value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have a PickerView and I want to initialize it with integer values. For example PickerView with all integers lower than 10.

Thank you

Comment: You have to put objects into a `NSArray`, so `NSNumber` could be a solution. What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly are you struggling with? Title of the question does not relate much to the description..

Comment: You can't add integer bcs Array contains only objects so add like .. [NSNumber numberWithInteger:<#(NSInteger)#>];

Comment: I initialize the PickerView with NSArray, but I can't add integers to this NSArray. For example all integers lower than 10

Comment: `@[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10]`

Answer (score 3):

```
NSArray *array =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9,nil];
```

Comment: 10 is an only an exmple, i have variable and i want to inialize the NSArray with all integers lower than this variable

Answer (score 3):

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        [yourArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger min = 1;
NSInteger max = 10;
NSInteger step = 1;

NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> *options = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSInteger index = 0; index < ceilf(((float)max)/step); index++)
{
    options[index] = @((index + min) * step);
}

NSLog(@"%@",options);
```

**An alternate approach:**

```
NSInteger from = 1;
NSInteger size = 10;
NSInteger step = 1;

NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> *options = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSInteger index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
    options[index] = @((index + from) * step);
}

NSLog(@"%@",options);
```

Both of the above print the following:

(
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10
)

Answer (score -1):

```
int yourInt = 5;
[myMutableArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:yourInt]]; have look on this
```

It will just sample code to add the int value to the array nothing else

Comment: I want many integer not only one, for example all integer lower than 10, I used a for loop but he doesn't work

Comment: Please put more effort into your answers than simply posting a code block. An explanation would be helpful. It would also be good to avoid including unformatted comments in your code examples.

Comment: @bgilham I just show how to add the int value into the the MutableArray nothing else

Comment: @bgilham it is not good why you give me negative points please check the above statement .